# How to create a TSQL Replace table function?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I am using SSMS 2008 and I have the following Scalar function to take a text string and remove all metatags from Microsoft Word.  The tags are enclosed in "<...>" and there can be any number of tags / record in one column.

I created a scalar function based off this code below to update each row in this column.  But this scalar function takes a super long time to complete.  Would a table function version of this be faster?  If so, how could I rewrite this function to make it table?

```
WHILE PATINDEX( '%[%]%', @str ) > 0 
    SET @str = REPLACE( @str, SUBSTRING( @str, 
            PATINDEX( '%[%]%', @str ), 1 ), '' ) 
SELECT @str
```

This table function almost works.  But it turns out that it doesn't work now.  The problem is that I am trying to use this function on a temp table.  And the original table does not have an int PK, and I cannot add a column to the original table.

So I tried creating a view based on this table and then adding a PK int column to it.  Because when I tried to create the view with this additional PK int column ("n"), it gave me an error:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'identity'.
```

But ALTER VIEW does not support adding columns.  Is there another way to do this?  Here is my original temp table I am trying to modify:

```
select [progress_note].[note_text], [progress_note].[event_log_id] 
INTO #TEMP_PN
from [evolv_cs].[dbo].[progress_note] 
group by [progress_note].[event_log_id], [progress_note].[note_text]
```

[note_text] is varchar(max) and event_log_id is uniqueidentifier.  So [note_text] contains a bunch of "<" and ">" chars.  How can I modify this dbo.ufn_StripHTML function?

I tried ur latest code and this is super fast!!  However, I got the following error after it went thru 5700 rows:

```
Msg 537, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.
```

Do u know what this is about?

Comment: SQL Server CLR is an option to consider.

Comment: You may need more rows in your Number table if your note_text length is > the 500 test example I provided.  Also make sure you test after modifying my varchar(8000) --> max.  Read more here to understand -->  http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres a function I wrote to remove HTML tags (pairs of <...>) using a set based approached.  I  am interested to see if you can repurpose to use to strip Word meta tags.

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
-- 1. create a number table (this is just a utility table)
-----------------------------------------------------------
set nocount on;
if object_id('dbo.Number') is not null
begin
    drop table dbo.Number;
end
go

create table dbo.Number (n int identity(1,1) primary key);

insert dbo.Number default values ;
while scope_identity() < 500
    insert dbo.Number default values ;

----------------------------------------------------------- 
-- 2. create the function (leverages the utility table)
-----------------------------------------------------------
if object_id('dbo.ufn_StripHTML') is not null
begin
    drop function dbo.ufn_StripHTML;
end
go
create function dbo.ufn_StripHTML
    (   @Input      varchar(8000),
        @Delimiter  char(1)
    )
returns varchar(8000)
as
begin

    declare @Output varchar(8000)
    select  @Input = replace(replace(@input, '<', @Delimiter), '>', @Delimiter)

    select @Output = isnull(@Output, '') + s
    from    (    select   row_number() over (order by n.n asc) [i],
                 substring(@Delimiter + @Input + @Delimiter, n.n + 1, charindex(@Delimiter, @Delimiter + @Input + @Delimiter, n.n + 1) - n.n - 1) [s]
            from    dbo.Number n
            where   n.n = charindex(@Delimiter, @Delimiter + @Input + @Delimiter, n.n) and
                 n.n <= len(@Delimiter + @Input)
            ) d
    where i % 2 = 1

    return @Output

end
go

-----------------------------------------------------------
--3. Example of calling the function when you query
-----------------------------------------------------------
if object_id('tempdb..TEMP_PN') is not null
    drop table #TEMP_PN;

create table #TEMP_PN (note_text varchar(max), event_log_id int);

insert into #TEMP_PN
    select '<b>Some very large bolded text here!</b>', 1 union all
    select 'no tags here', 2 union all
    select '<html><body><h1>My First Heading</h1><p>My first paragraph.</p></body></html>', 3

select  [Strip] = dbo.ufn_StripHTML(note_text, '|'), 
        [Orig] = note_text,
        event_log_id
from    #TEMP_PN
```

Edit: ported scalar to table

```
alter function dbo.ufn_StripHTMLTable
    (   @Input      varchar(8000),
        @Delimiter  char(1)
    )
returns @ret table (OutString varchar(8000))
as
begin
    declare @Output varchar(8000)
    select  @Input = replace(replace(@input, '<', @Delimiter), '>', @Delimiter)

    select @Output = isnull(@Output, '') + s
    from    (   select   row_number() over (order by n.n asc) [i],
                        substring(@Delimiter + @Input + @Delimiter, n.n + 1, charindex(@Delimiter, @Delimiter + @Input + @Delimiter, n.n + 1) - n.n - 1) [s]
                from    dbo.Number n
                where   n.n = charindex(@Delimiter, @Delimiter + @Input + @Delimiter, n.n) and
                        n.n <= len(@Delimiter + @Input)
            ) d
    where i % 2 = 1;

    insert into @ret
        values(@Output);

    return;
end
```

Comment: Thanks!  I am curious though--what is the @delimiter used for?

Comment: Just need to give it a character that is not in the data to be parsed. I use a pipe, but in case you have pipes in your data its configurable

Comment: Hey Nathan, can u please look one more time at my question I updated please?

Comment: @salvationishere I updated my post, hopefully it makes better sense now.  The number table is just a utility table, you dont need to alter your `[progress_note]` table or create a view.  Check out my example use in step 3... just call the function when you `select`

Comment: Thanks Nathan, but can u take one more look at my description?  I tried running ur code.  I appreciate u for updating it to be more specific to my situation, however, I am getting the described error message now.

Comment: never mind.  I think i found the problem.  My @input was varchar(max), so I just altered the function to be max instead of 8000 and now it looks like it's working!  Thank u so much!

Comment: It did work, however, I think a table function would be faster.  Do u have any table functions that would work for this?

Comment: I added table example, let us know if its any faster.  You can probably further optimize this but I dont have time today :)